# Word ContentControl handle?

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, vsto

I’m using Word ContentControls to present & synchronize data coming from backend services. I need a way to indicate that content of a given control has changed. One way I can imagine this is to change style around given Range residing in ContentControl. Although this may not be as flexible as requirements I’ve got. The other way I can envision is to use GDI to draw necessary indicators myself. I know I can get handle of main word window but I’m struggling with finding a way to obtain handle to any CustomControl in it. Is that possible?

Comment: From your tags I assume you are using VSTO; with VSTO you can manipulate a content control.  Why don't you use change tracking/redlining, or comments to identify the change?

Comment: Yes I'm using VSTO. What you are suggesting is one of the possibilities. At this stage I'm all about options.

Answer (score -1):

Use Microsoft's SPY++
i believe it can be downloaded from here

http://mdb-blog.blogspot.co.il/2010/11/microsoft-spy-or-spyxx-for-download.html

Information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: you shouldn't need to download this really. It is shipped with Visual Studio (if you installed it from the Tools branch) and can be found under the Tools menu

Comment: And how this can help me during a runtime?

Comment: You shouldn't answer questions asking for resources.